# Visual Studio 2013 Application Publishing Missing Install Directory

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, publishing

So I went through the publishing wizard included with 2013 ultimate edition and I see I can configure everything except the most important part of an installation, where to copy the files to when the application is installed by the user.  I want it to install to C:\Program Files (x86)\Program Name  However, this just cannot be done. I do see an installation folder URL option but I think this probably refers to the location where the setup files are placed, not the location where the actual program is installed to. Am I missing something here?

This is a windows forms application. It has an exe file that has to be copied somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need InstallShield2013LimitedEdition.
Go here and download it for free http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio
register and get the key