# Making an installer for a VS 2013 Express VB.Net program

Tags: vb.net, installation, visual-studio-express

Using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, I made a VB.Net WinForms application for someone and am trying to generate an installer/setup file so that they can install it on their own computer.

I did use the Publish Wizard to produce a set of files which has a setup.exe file, a .application file for the project, an autorun.inf file, and an Application Files folder with .deploy, .manifest and .application files in it.  I also have a spreadsheet document added as a resource, but it ends up in another folder generated by this setup process.

How can I produce a successful installer to send the person this program?
This is what I was hoping to accomplish:

1. Have the setup prompt the user for the destination folder
2. Have the spreadsheet be installed to the same folder as the
   executable

Thank you to anyone who is able to assist.

Comment: maybe you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824133/visual-studio-2013-application-publishing-missing-install-directory/22824574#22824574

Comment: I had already downloaded that, and found that it is not licensed to work with the Express versions of Visual Studio.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an MSI with the [free edition of Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), following the linked tutorial. It's a 5 minutes tutorial that will generate at the end your installer.

VS Express has its own limitations, this is whyone is that you cannot import the binary files generated by your solution directly into the project (neither the one generated by Advanced Installer or the one generated by IS).

The solution is to manually add your files in the project, just drag and drop them in Files and Folders page from Advanced Installer. There you can also create the shortcut for your EXE, so the end user can launch your application.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan!  A colleague suggested a similar solution using Inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) which seems to be doing the trick.  I thought I needed to account for .Net and all of the references and was expecting it to be more complex than it actually needed to be.

Comment: Inno is good too Rick, but just make sure you are aware of, Inno Setup is not able to create MSI installers (i.e. Windows Installer based), which is kind of what everybody running on Windows prefers. While as Advanced Installer is built especially for that, or, if you prefer scripting you could check out Wix Toolset (http://wixtoolset.org/), as this is currently the best OSS solution for building MSI packages